# Catalog price rule stops at midnight

Tags: catalog-price-rules, ee-1.12

I have a catalog price rule for a group of products with start date 25/06/14 and end date 30/06/14. This rule stops working at midnight 29/06/14. This happens every weekend for campaigns that should be available until monday evening. Cron is running every minute. Anyone have a clue why they stop working a day in advance?

Answer (score 4):

I had a lot of issues with the catalog price rules reindexing before.
My latest solution (that seams to work) was to change the hour when the cron for reindexing of catalog rules run.
Here is why.
I'm using a time zone with GMT+2.
The default cron is set to run at 1.00.
So I put a log to see when the cron starts and when it ends.
My surprise was to see the following:

```
2014-06-06T23:00:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Start daily update
2014-06-06T23:00:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): End daily update
```

So the hour that was logged was the GMT hour (23.00).
And the cron calculates the dates to for which the reindex should be done like this:

```
$fromDate = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')-1);
```

So it does not use the internal date methods but directy `date` I thought it may have something to do with timezone settings.
So I made the cron run at one hour when my timezone and GMT timezone are in the same day.
Moved it to 2:10.
I didn't have any issues since then.

Comment: hi @marius , check here : http://prntscr.com/7535c7 also i am using time zone with GMT + 5:30 and i did't gave any date in catalog price rules. so what i have to do to get solution?

Comment: can you please inform me in which file and path you changed that code?

Comment: @BabyinMagento2.The file that determines when the cron runs is `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml` Look for the line `<cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>`

Comment: that's fine, i got the line, where i have to add it this code :" $fromDate = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')-1);" or what changes i have  to do now ?

Comment: you don't need to add that line anywhere

Comment: hi @Marius thanks for your support as always, i got an solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night

Comment: Hi Marius, If I change the cron job (catalogrule_apply_all) to run at 5.00 AM, my time settings is GMT+4.30.  
Should I change the schedule of reindex job (catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all) also to a time after 5.00 AM.  Thanks

Comment: @Ted. I'm not sure about it, but I think it's better to be safe and move the reindex after the catalog rule aplly index.

Comment: thanks Marius for reply, I was stepping through the catalogrule_apply_all and find that there is a Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh which is doing a re index. So is it OK if we dint change time of catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all.

Comment: @marius did you made an override for config.xml?

Comment: @krybbio I wrote this 4 years ago. I don't remember exactly what I did, but if I had to do it again, based on my own answer I would change the cron expression for the cronjob via my own config.xml. Try adding this to the `config.xml` in one of your modules `<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <catalogrule_apply_all>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>10 2 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
            </catalogrule_apply_all>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>`

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is ending at 00:00:00 30/06/14. Try adding a time to the datetime string in that format, or bumping the day up by one. Simply setting the end date to 30/06/14 tells the system to end the promotion the minute after 23:59:00 29/06/14, which is the first minute (00:00:00) of 30/06/14.

Answer (score 1):

Change timezone in  configuration to GMT.  Apply the catalog rules  now.

Revert back timezone to your desired selection if needed.
I have a fashion store [www.huzoorwomen.com](http://www.huzoorwomen.com) that uses same rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Default Store Timezone to match your server timezone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, the issue exists when there is an offset of the local timezone greater than +01:00.

Basically just because magento is using the gmtTimestamp for the rule date which in the above stated case results in the day before today.

Therefor I developed a small module https://github.com/Chuvisco88/Chuvisco_CatalogRuleFix to fix the issue.
If someone ever has this problem, please give it a try.