# Promotions/Catalog Price Rules - Applying product's price rule only for 2 days

Tags: catalog-price-rules, discount, date

I am facing a problem with my Magento (ver. 1.8.0.0) and Catalog price rules.

I have placed a Catalogue Rule in Promotions/Catalog Price Rules. The Rule is 15% discount of a Customer Group in a specific product Category, until the end of this month (To Date 7/31/14).

Before some days, I realized that when I was logged into the customer group, I could see the discount prices normally in the Category view. **But**, when I clicked on a product, the discount price has not being applied to the item, although in the category I *view* the Discount but the product itself has no discount at all!

After trying almost everything, I realized that changing "From Date" to 48 hours back from present date, everything worked fine. So, I login everyday and change the "From Date" to 1 day before my present date and the issue disappears, but this is not a solution at all!

Is there any help for this issue?

> *For testing purposes, you can check at: `http://pathart.gr/`
>   The discount category is: `http://pathart.gr/season.html`
>   email: mytest@customertest.gr
>   pass: letmein

Comment: Not sure but maybe it's related to this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25579/146

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Can you explain me, please, the way to made the cron run at one hour when my timezone and GMT timezone are in the same day? How am i supposed to figure this out?

Comment: You need to change the cron expression for the `catalogrule_apply_all`. Add in the `config.xml` file of one of your modules this: <crontab>
        `<jobs>
            <catalogrule_apply_all>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>10 2 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
            </catalogrule_apply_all>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>`

Comment: Nothing worked with this. Its keeping the price rule for only 2 days. Every 2 days i have to change again the "From Date"

Answer (score 1):

As advised by [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26282/promotions-catalog-price-rules-applying-products-price-rule-only-for-2-days#comment36661_26282), I went into `/app/code/local/Any_Module_Author/Any_Module_Name/etc/config.xml` and at the end, after `</config>`, I add:

```
<crontab> 
    <jobs> 
        <catalogrule_apply_all> 
            <schedule> 
                <cron_expr>10 2 * * *</cron_expr> 
            </schedule> 
        </catalogrule_apply_all> 
    </jobs> 
</crontab>
```

Then I went into my Promotions/Catalog Price Rule and changed the "From Date" to 1 month before today in order to test it. I made the Cache clear-ups and until now everything seems to work properly.

On the other hand, when I changed the "From Date" to "Today", the rule didn't work, but this is not a big deal because you can set it one day back.